# Getting error with Enterprise API: Illegal assignment from list to list?

Tags: soap-api, java, enterprise

Integrating salesforce with salesforce using Enterprise wsdl and and it's api's.While doing that I have got an error. 
I am using  records property  and assigning to sobject array so that I can loop through returned records and do further processing .Please look at the code below.

The line which is giving me an error is and the error is:-Illegal assignment from list to list .

**sObject[] records=g.records;**

Entire code is being written in apex.

I am sure what is that I missing .

```
enterpriseSoapSforceCom.soap binding = new enterpriseSoapSforceCom.soap();
enterpriseSoapSforceCom.LoginResult lr = binding.login('nitins1234@yahoo.com', 'XXXXXXX');
system.debug('The value in the lr of loginresult is' + lr);

//Update the binding endpoint as per the LoginResult
binding.endpoint_x = lr.ServerUrl;

System.debug('The value after setting the binding of the binding.endpoint_x+' + binding.endpoint_x);

binding.SessionHeader = new enterpriseSoapSforceCom.SessionHeader_element();
binding.SessionHeader.sessionid = lr.sessionid;

System.debug('The value in variable of sesion id is' + binding.SessionHeader.sessionid);

string s = 'Select firstname,lastname from contact limit 3';
//enterpriseSoapSforceCom.QueryResult l = binding.describeglobal();

enterpriseSoapSforceCom.QueryResult g = binding.query(s);
boolean b = false;

if (g.size > 0)
{
  b = true;
  System.debug('The value in the boolean variable b is' + b);
  while (!g.done)
  {
    /**/ sObject[] records = g.records; /**/ // Illegal assignment from list to list.
    for (integer i = 0; i < records.Length; i++)
    {
      Contact con = (Contact)records[i];
      string fName = con.FirstName;
      string lName = con.LastName;

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You're using the wrong data type. It's likely that SObject[] is not the correct data type. Take a look at the generated Apex Class for the WSDL, it'll give you the correct data type to use. You may need to JSON.serialize/deserialize to cast it successfully into a native SObject.

Answer (score 1):

The sObject that is returned from the Enterprise API is not the same as the native Apex sObject. You will need to prefix it with the name of your WSDL2Apex generated class.